# Jenkins iOS archive error with Pods FIRCoreDiagnostics.m normal armv7

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, cocoapods, archive

I have a project using **cocoapods (use_frameworks!)** and **Jenkins** as my CI server.

Everything works fine on my local environment, including pod install, build, archive...

But when using Jenkins always **archive failed**

**Here is error message:**

> Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>
> (1 failure)
>
> Build step '執行 Shell' marked build as failure
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Message when archiving:

[image]

**My jenkins configuration:**

**Run buildstep before SCM runs**

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/local/bin/pod install
```

**Run script**

```
## Archive the project

xcodebuild archive \
-workspace "${WORKSPACE}" \
-scheme "${SCHEME}" \
-configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
-sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" \
-archivePath "${ARCHIVEPATH}" \
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${SIGNING_IDENTITY}" \
PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER}"
```

---

Something I have tried and still not working:

**setup environment variables**

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12164

[image]

**export UTF-8 encoding when Run Script**

[image]

---

**If you guys need more message, please let me know...
Thanks**

Comment: Do the CocoaPods and Xcode versions match between local and CI?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Yes, cocoapods 1.8.4, Xcode10.1

Comment: Maybe the CI needs `pod install --repo-update`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, I have tried the solution, not working lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, I found the solution by myself. The reason is that I use wrong pods grammar.

I refer the solution from here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2100

> **The issue is using the deprecated version of the Google pod that forces in an extra old version of the GoogleUtilities pod that doesn't have the Environment subspec with the GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h header.**

I seems like the same problem. So, I change my pods grammar from

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 6.13.0'
```

to

```
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '~> 6.1.7'
```

Everything works well.

Comment: After searching for many issues like this i'll found your hint to the deprecated pod format.  Simple delete the slashes and run pod install. Thank you very much!